# Kamal Not Running to Completion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, sshkit, kamal

I'm using Kamal to setup my Rails application.  I can't get passed the basic 'kamal setup'.  I've tried various approaches, like kamal setup --verbose, but I can't get at why the setup is failing. I believe it has something to do with the error below. Which appears to be from a docker push command that SSHKit is running, but I can't see the actual command that ran and caused the error.  Below is a portion of the output from the command `kamal setup --verbose > kamal_setup_log`

```
 DEBUG [8a56a5fa]   #27 naming to docker.io/library/redacted:latest done
 DEBUG [8a56a5fa]   #27 DONE 2.3s
 DEBUG [8a56a5fa]   The push refers to repository [docker.io/library/redacted]
 DEBUG [8a56a5fa]   dd6aa59e1b43: Preparing
 DEBUG [8a56a5fa]   e91ce5e22f33: Preparing
 DEBUG [8a56a5fa]   b2807a8ceb3b: Preparing
 DEBUG [8a56a5fa]   abe293a67997: Preparing
 DEBUG [8a56a5fa]   769106a39780: Preparing
 DEBUG [8a56a5fa]   efc10388b247: Preparing
 DEBUG [8a56a5fa]   3400e3ecbe22: Preparing
 DEBUG [8a56a5fa]   c008d1cffc59: Preparing
 DEBUG [8a56a5fa]   413b8e3348a8: Preparing
 DEBUG [8a56a5fa]   2e27e93293e7: Preparing
 DEBUG [8a56a5fa]   340af2f9ccca: Preparing
 DEBUG [8a56a5fa]   ec983b166360: Preparing
 DEBUG [8a56a5fa]   c008d1cffc59: Waiting
 DEBUG [8a56a5fa]   340af2f9ccca: Waiting
 DEBUG [8a56a5fa]   ec983b166360: Waiting
 DEBUG [8a56a5fa]   efc10388b247: Waiting
 DEBUG [8a56a5fa]   413b8e3348a8: Waiting
 DEBUG [8a56a5fa]   3400e3ecbe22: Waiting
 DEBUG [8a56a5fa]   2e27e93293e7: Waiting
 DEBUG [8a56a5fa]   denied: requested access to the resource is denied
  Finished all in 35.3 seconds
Releasing the deploy lock...
```

Answer (score 2):

In deploy.yml, I had

image: image-name

NOT:

image: user-repository/image-name

That was the fix.

The second you post a question to Stackoverflow you realize that you did something stupid.